# Can JUnit compare two XML files at the end of a test and do a diff?

Tags: junit

Can JUnit compare two XML files at the end of a test and do a diff? Does anyone have an online example of that?

Comment: JUnit has nothing built in.  You have to parse the two, walk the trees, and decide if they're the same.  Why wouldn't a String comparison not be sufficient?

Comment: Well in this case some branches will be always different. Only some branches need to be the same and those are the ones that need to be diffed. Cheers!

Comment: XMLUnit does precisely that.

Comment: Then I'd compare the subtrees that need to be identical using String comparison.  Trees are recursive

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you, maybe not. If you are looking to discern a small difference, then this simple example might do the trick. I like [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) for the fluent assertions, but also because it gives some useful failure messages!

```
package example;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

import com.google.common.base.Joiner;
import org.junit.Test;

public class XmlDiffExample {

    private static final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    private Joiner j = Joiner.on(NEWLINE);

    private String[] xml = new String[] {
        "<?xml version='1.0'?>",
        "<container>",
            "<greeting>hello, %s!</greeting>",
        "</container>"
    };

    @Test
    public void should_diff_xml_docs() {
        assertThat(getDoc1()).isEqualTo(getDoc2());
    }

    private String getDoc1() {
        return String.format(j.join(xml), "world");
    }

    private String getDoc2() {
        return String.format(j.join(xml), "foo");
    }

}
```

yields:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...>
<greeting>hello, [foo]!</greeting>
</cont...> but was:<...>
<greeting>hello, [world]!</greeting>
</cont...>
```